# Discarding "Anonymous" exception while joining tables

Tags: c#, linq, fastmember

I got confused, how to join for example two tables without getting the "Anonymous" exception; for example the following code fraction:

```
 var result = (from prod in context.ProductsTbls
                              join imag in context.ProductImagesTbls
                              on prod.Id equals imag.ProductId
                              where prod.UserId == 4 && imag.IsDefaultImage == true
                              select new
                              {
                                  Id = prod.Id,
                                  ProductName = prod.ProductName,
                                  ProductDescription = prod.ProductDescription,
                                  ProductCategory = prod.ProductCategory,
                                  ProductPricePerDay = prod.ProductPricePerDay,
                                  ProductPricePerWeek = prod.ProductPricePerWeek,
                                  ProductPricePerMonth = prod.ProductPricePerMonth,
                                  CreationDate = prod.CreationDate,
                                  ModificationDate = prod.ModificationDate,
                                  Image = imag.Image
                              }).ToList();


                IEnumerable<ProductsTbl> data =
 (IEnumerable<ProductsTbl>)result.ToList(); // Exception appears here
                DataTable table = new DataTable();

                using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data, "Id", "Image"))
                {
                    table.Load(reader);
                }
```

After executing the above code, am getting this exception :

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 
        'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`10[System.Int32,System.Str
    ing,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1
    [System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]
    ,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Byte[]]]' to type 
    'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ClassLibrary1.ProductsTbl]'.'
```

Comment: Pretty much exactly what it says. By using `select new` you're "creating" a new type, that isn't of type `ProductsTbl`.

Comment: So don't try to cast to `ProductsTbl`. Why would you? Also, please use the tag [fastmember] for these questions.

Comment: @GertArnold question edited. :)

Comment: What is `ObjectReader`? I would imagine the exception is no longer the same.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli As I mentioned, I didn't mean that the above could is my current case, it is just an example, my issue about that in most cases I got the anonymous problem.

Comment: Which line of code above throws the exception? If it doesn't throw an exception, please show us the code sample that **does**.

Comment: I reverted your revision because you removed the part that threw the exception, invalidating the whole question. Also marked as duplicate of one of many questions on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when you need the result of a LINQ query to be an `IEnumerable` or collection of a certain type, you need to create instances of that type in the `select`.

So, instead of `select new {` ... `}` you would use:

```
select new ProductsTbl {
    // put field values here
}
```